# vb.net Copy Structure not Address

Tags: vb.net, copy, structure

I'm trying to copy data from a Structure to a temporary structure so that if a user clicks the cancel button I have not modified the original data. It appears that the = is assigning the address to the new structure and not simply copying the data.  If they hit Save Button then I want to copy the modified structure to the working structure and if they hit Cancel, then I simply destroy the Temp Structure.

What happens is that any change I make in the Temp Structure is reflected in the working structure. How do I keep these separate without having to to copy each element of the structure on it's own?

Note: OutputData is an array of the same "SortKeysStruct" Structure.

Thank You!

```
    Dim TempOutput As new OutputDataStructure

Private Sub OutputDetailsForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TempOutput = OutputData(ActivePanelIx)
End Sub

Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
    OutputData(ActivePanelIx) = TempOutput

    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub CancelBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CancelBtn.Click
    OutputData(ActivePanelIx) = TempOutput

    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: You keep saying "structure" but if the `OutputDataStructure` type is really a structure rather than a class then what you want would already be happening. Assigning a value-type variable to another variable does indeed copy the value. Classes are reference types though, so an assignment copies a reference to the object rather than the object.  That is by design, so that large and possibly self-referencing objects aren't recreated over and over in memory.  If you want to duplicate a reference-type object then you have to do so explicitly, either manually or via its own `Copy` or `Clone` method.

Comment: For more information see [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)

Comment: It is really a structure and not a class.... If it were a class how would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this code in a new Console app project and you will see that a structure (value type) behaves as you want while a class (reference type) does not but rather requires you to create a copy yourself:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim t1A As New Type1 With {.Text = "Initial"}
        Dim t2A As New Type2 With {.Text = "Initial"}
        Dim t3A As New Type3 With {.Text = "Initial"}

        Dim t1B = t1A
        Dim t2B = t2A
        Dim t3B = DirectCast(t3A.Clone(), Type3)

        t1B.Text = "Final"
        t2B.Text = "Final"
        t3B.Text = "Final"

        Console.WriteLine(t1A.Text)
        Console.WriteLine(t2A.Text)
        Console.WriteLine(t3A.Text)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module

Public Structure Type1
    Public Property Text As string
End Structure


Public Class Type2
    Public Property Text As String
End Class


Public Class Type3
    Implements ICloneable

    Public Property Text As String

    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Return New Type3 With {.Text = Text}
    End Function

End Class
```

That code will show that the `Text` properties of `t1A` (value type) and `t3A` (cloned reference type) are not modified while that of `t2A` (reference type) is.

Comment: An interesting thing here. My structure was not Public but once I added Public it worked the way I wanted/intended it to..... Thanks

Comment: That sounds odd.  You have your answer so you may not want to spend any more time on this but, if you don't mind, could you edit your question and provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your original issue as I'd like to look more closely at it to see if I can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond... I must have missed the notification that you responded... Sorry and thank you again.